# Div height doesn't expand when I have a fieldset inside

Tags: css, html, height, fieldset

I have a div that expands to the height of it's content. It works fine if I put only paragraphs (

) or a table inside but when I put a fieldset it doesn't expand to its height.

I have used jsfiddle to make an example http://jsfiddle.net/33hgK/4/ . 
Anyone else had this problem?

I appreciate any answers I receive.

Comment: fieldsets are a bit of a red headed step child to most browsers. It doesn't adhere to what we'd consider normal dom behavior--especially in terms of styling.

Comment: agree with @DA , i class a fieldset as being a concept, i think either adding a `display:block` to it, or clearing the float will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the float:left; from fieldset#infofields

http://jsfiddle.net/33hgK/5/

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I was using float:left because I was displaying two fieldsets next to each other. Removing float:left but leaving display:inline in my project, both fieldsets are on the same row but the first is moved a bit lower, I'll have a look through the rest of my code to see if there's something else messing that up. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Maybe you can put a div wrapper wiit float:left around the fieldset.

Comment: Antoher problem: float:center; in your body can cause the problem, too. CENTER is not a proper parameter for float. Only left or right is allowed (it is set to center cause of the text-align in body). http://jsfiddle.net/33hgK/17/ (float in body set to center and wrapper around fieldsets, but now you need a wrapper around the div to position it to center ( margin:auto)